# Is "dehabilitating" an acceptable word?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I see 'debilitating' a lot and I've always inwardly considered it a shortening (if you'll pardon my insular attitude, even an *Americanisation*) of the longer word 'dehabilitating', in the same vein as words like *airplane* and *esophagus*.

It's taken me until recently to actually Google the words and I find very few uses of the latter – enough to confine it to the refuse heap of "common mistakes" – but I wonder if it doesn't have some archaic root or extinct word with which it is being confused, as it seems like rather a few people are picking up on what would otherwise be a fairly arbitrary extension to the word.

Any ideas?

Comment: Huh.  When I'm looking at them, I would assume both are words, but I would assume that they did not mean the same thing.  Different associations, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I was just linked to this Wiktionary page for "dehabilitation":

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dehabilitation

Which I believe is the source for the confusion; this closes my question thus.

Comment: Yep, the word is a bit of jargon -- not quite psychobabble but in the same region.

Comment: Probably the more common term *rehabilitation* also contributed; it would be easy to (subconsciously) assume that there must be an English term *habilitate* which formed the stem of *de[ha]bilitate*. (There is, in fact, such a word, but it's essentially obsolete now and was never common.)

Answer (score 1):

The two terms appear to be related etymologically: ***[-bilis "strength"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=debility&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> ***Debilitate:*** 1530s, from Latin debilitatus, past participle of debilitare "to weaken," ***from debilis*** "weak" (see debility). Related: Debilitated; debilitating -
>
> ***Habilitate*** - c. 1600 (transitive) "to qualify," from Medieval Latin habilitatus, past participle of habilitare, ***from habile*** "fit, suitable" (see able)

(Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dehabilitating&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdehabilitating%3B%2Cc0) shows usage of the term *dehabilitating* from the '50s.